# Selenium string issue using text() command

Tags: python, string, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
#####howl bot
###Made By John
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import selenium.common.exceptions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\hoagl\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://howl.gg")
driver.maximize_window()

while True:

    account = input("are you logged in yes, no = ")

    while account.lower() not in ("yes", "no"):
        account = input("Are you logged in? yes/no = ")

    if account == "yes":
        print("success")
        break

while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        giveaway = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/text()').text()
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]').click()
        print(button)
        accont = input("print good to go?")
        print("giveaway Entered")
        print("Current Time =", current_time)

        time.sleep(5)
```

on the code
`giveaway = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/text()').text()`
I need to find out how I can actually get the text from the website I'm having issues as I com back with the error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Remove text() from xpath and the end and use .text instead.

Comment: Also use driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"") instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cause text is a property, not a method.
Instead of

```
giveaway = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/text()').text()
```

use

```
giveaway = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/text()').text
```

without the ()